# NullPointer excepetion when setAdapter for spinner on menu

Tags: android, menu, spinner

I want to create a spinner on the Menu.

However when I was doing the initialization of the spinner item,

I encounterer the NullPointer exception and I've tried serveral times and it

remained existent.

The code is below

**The menu xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Lang_spinner"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:title="@string/git_lang"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**And here is the onCreateOptionsMenu part**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        MenuItem lang_spnItem =menu.findItem(R.id.Lang_spinner);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(lang_spnItem);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Lang,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't know where the problems happened.

Hope someone can point it out, I'm grateful to it. Thanks

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: Can you please post your LogCat Message error ?